# GitLab, Can't login in Docker registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am a GitLab User. I produce with a groff script a book with 900 pages. The output will be stored in the output folder. When an author make some changes and push into GitLab, the Docker image will produce this book.

The idea is to build a docker container and store the container in the GitLab registry. The build of the container works fine, but I get an error message.

The error is in the run script. The docker login in not correct.

```sh
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  CONTAINER_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/test
  DOCKER_IMAGE: paperboy
  TAG: 0.1.0

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - release
  - run

before_script:
  - docker login registry.gitlab.com --username gitlab+deploy-token-0000 --password 3435563
  - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
  - apk update && apk add --no-cache
  - rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE
    - docker tag  $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE:latest $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE:$TAG
    - docker push $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE:$TAG
  only:
    - master

run:
  stage: run
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE
    - docker run --rm  -v $(pwd)/data/:/home/data 
    -v $(pwd)/output/:/home/output
    -v $(pwd)/output/csv/:/home/output/csv
    -v $(pwd)/output/pdf/:/home/output/pdf paperboy
    - rm -rf "%CACHE_PATH%/%CI_PIPELINE_ID%"
  only:
    - master
```

This is the idea of the run script in my .gitlab-ci.yml. I get this error message:

```sh
$ docker run --rm 
  -v $(pwd)/data/:/home/data
  -v $(pwd)/output/:/home/output
  -v $(pwd)/output/csv/:/home/output/csv
  -v $(pwd)/output/pdf/:/home/output/pdf $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE

  - git add .

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"-\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
time="2019-09-10T10:55:51Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

```sh
run:
  stage: run
  script:
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u gitlab+deploy-token-95492 -p $DEPLOY_TOKEN
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE
    - docker images | grep paperboy
    - docker run --rm
      -v $(pwd)/data/:/home/data
      -v $(pwd)/output/:/home/output
      -v $(pwd)/output/csv/:/home/output/csv
      -v $(pwd)/output/pdf/:/home/output/pdf
      $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE
      - git add .
      - git commit -m "Update"
      - git push origin master
      - rm -rf "%CACHE_PATH%/%CI_PIPELINE_ID%"
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning about the password being stored unencrypted can be ignored.

For the run error, you've specified `paperboy` as the image instead of `registry.gitlab.com/test/paperboy`. Since you already have variables that combine together for the image name, you should probably use them instead of the hard-coded `paperboy` value.

```
run:
  stage: run
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE
    - docker run --rm 
      -v $(pwd)/data/:/home/data
      -v $(pwd)/output/:/home/output
      -v $(pwd)/output/csv/:/home/output/csv
      -v $(pwd)/output/pdf/:/home/output/pdf
      $CONTAINER_IMAGE/$DOCKER_IMAGE
    - rm -rf "%CACHE_PATH%/%CI_PIPELINE_ID%"
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: It works fine. But I can't see the /output/csv and /output/pdf folder in the GitLab Repo. What have I forgotten?

Comment: Are you expecting your container's outputs to show up in the repository? Your code would need to somehow make commits to the repo. They're not going to just show up.

Comment: One other thing you should know is that the run script, as written, is running the container inside of Docker-in-Docker, inside the context of the run job. The container will be killed as soon as the job stops running.

Comment: Is it possible to give me some lines of code? I can't find the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the `pass` package on your GitLab runner machine.

If your machine is Ubuntu so execute this cmd:

```
apt install pass
```